# Default value of datetime picker AngularJS/MomentJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I'm using datepicker from here: http://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/

How can I set this default value?

```
<input class="form-control"
       placeholder="Select date: To"
       ng-model="ctrl.datepicker">
```

What should I write in controller to get default date - today?

```
$scope.ctrl.datepicker=?;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set today as default date using by passing `moment();` only.

So in your case you have to do `$scope.ctrl.datepicker = moment();`

Below is working example:

HTML:

```
  <div class="form-control"
       moment-picker="ctrl.div.stringDate"
       format="YYYY-MM-DD"
       locale="en"
       ng-model="ctrl.div.momentDate">
    <a class="pull-right"
       ng-if="ctrl.div.stringDate"
       ng-click="ctrl.div.momentDate = undefined">
      &times;
    </a>
    <span ng-class="{'text-muted': !ctrl.div.stringDate}">
      {{ ctrl.div.stringDate || 'Select a date...' }}
    </span>
  </div>
```

JavaScript controller:

```
ctrl.setToday = function (which) {
  ctrl[which].momentDate = moment();
};
```

Here is complete code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/3tf1IeOoZimt9V6HQnSp?p=preview